# WiFi keeps searching and icon issue

Tags: network, wifi, icon

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) with MacOS Sierra.

My issue is that the WiFi keeps searching indefinitely, even when I'm stably connected to my home network. My house is quite isolated so my hotspot is the only one in range.

In addition the icons don't reflect the actual signal strength (when choosing the network), and the one in the top bar is constantly animated as if during the connection phase.

I have no idea how to solve this. What can I do?

EDIT: this is specific to this device, all the other devices I own have no issues connecting. Also I want to specify that connection is not the issue, meaning that I can browse internet just fine and even use `ssh` as if nothing was wrong.

WiFi Diagnostic tool highlights no issues with the connection (as expected as I'm not seeing any).

I performed all the operations listed in the Apple support page, which frankly seem supremely useless, and nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does this happen to every device that connects via wifi to your network or only the Mac?  See [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202222) for some steps you can do to start troubleshooting.  If it still happens, pls come back and [edit] your question with the updated info.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I had already did all those very basic operations.

Comment: Have you tried to [reset your Network interface?](http://mandarapte.com/apple/reset-rebuild-network-settings-preferences-including-ethernet-wifi-bluetooth-system-default-mac-macintosh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the icon giving you issues, not the connection, then try removing the icon from the menu bar, restarting your machine, and then putting it back.

To remove the "Wifi Status" menu bar icon, drag it out of the menu bar *while* holding the <kbd>command</kbd> key.

Restart your machine. To put the icon back, go to **System Preferences > Network > Show Wifi Status in Menu Bar**.

---

If this doesn't work, then [reset your Network interface](http://mandarapte.com/apple/reset-rebuild-network-settings-preferences-including-ethernet-wifi-bluetooth-system-default-mac-macintosh/), which will erase your previous configuration and set it back to default.

Comment: This worked for me at first. After a while went by I restarted my computer again and it started happening again... not sure why